# Render a radiobuttonlist horizontally

Tags: asp.net, webforms, radiobuttonlist

Can a radio button list be rendered as follows

```
0    1    2    3    4    5
r    r    r    r    r    r
```

where `r` represents a radiobutton in the radiobuttonlist and the text above it is the part of the radiobutton text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own `MyCustomRadioButtonList` and override `Render` to display it the way you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the accepted way to create either a radio or check box list. Users expect to find the text to the right of the radio button or check box and you would really have to have a compelling reason not to adhere to this convention.